# Grabbing actual selection name without signs

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to add in the name of the selection into the QLineEdit, however instead of grabbing just the name, the result displayed includes `['']` parentheses etc

And hence I would like to know how can I add in the text without those signs?

The following is my code, in which `currentTxt` is the name of my QLineEdit:

```
sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
self.currentTxt.setText(str(sel))
```

I tried using `.text()` but it gives me error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`..

Also, can I ask how do I set the selection to check if it is of a particular type, example camera?

Answer (score 0):

selection returns a list. You need to get only one item out of the list:

```
sel = cmds.ls(sl=True) or  ['']  # so you don't crash on empy selections
first = sel[0]
self.currentTxt.setText(first)
```